# Android : How to use Cache in ion library?

Tags: android, caching, android-ion

In my case, I want to load data from Cache. If there is cache load from cache else load from network. How can I use caching in [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion)?

```
    private void loadION() {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("loading");
    progressDialog.show();
    Ion.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url)
            .setBodyParameter("tag", "annual_schedule").asString()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, String str) {
                    Message.Toast(getApplicationContext(), str);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: You mean you wish to know when the image is available right away (exists in memory) ? loading from the disk-cache can also take a long time (compared to how fast the UI should be), and should be treated like the network.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't ask about image. I asked abt String Response.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for missing this detail. Could be the same though.

Comment: i have same question, and how to free cache?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ion will automatically cache GET requests. This is a POST request, and can not be cached by the library.

Furthermore, cached requests can't be used right away, since disk I/O is still treated as a blocking call. It will still be an asynchronous request.

Comment: Hi koush,i always obtain 'Response is not cacheable' with get request and json content. I've, also, installed root cache as http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html but it doesn't works

Comment: @Premier You'll need to set the Cache-Control header server side for Ion to cache the GET request.